# One time solution for a web form to collect user data? (Excel?)

Tags: excel, forms, validation, security

I have a small and simple project for 3 weeks duration. The application is a classic wizard type of form:

- A conditional form that have a series of question, depending on the answer to each (or combinations) of questions, the users are then taken to different set of questions.
- Questions are of variety in yes/no/dropdown/text and adding line items (i.e. how many cats do you have? 6? here are 6 name fields to fill out). There are about 100 questions total with several possible routes.

Here is the thing, the client is currently interested in using Excel for this (i.e. macro to hide/show columns, and macro to add rows.). Then to collect information, they would send out the excel file

I want to know what other technologies (especially in the web space) that can do this (instead of horrendous excel). Note, before you suggest many Online Form builders Apps out there, that's not possible. The client IT would reject almost all external hosted solutions. They would rather have an app build to deploy on their server, behind their firewalls. Because of the enterprise security level requirements, even our client is reluctant to approach their IT (but ironically resort to Excel Macro since IT simply hand-waving at Excels' security as "good")

If I was to create this for of application in house, where should I start and what technology stack should I consider? Thoughts on complexity and time of that?

Thanks

Comment: Office 365 offers Microsoft Forms, which can use conditional branching. The form is filled out in the browser or on a smart phone and the returning data is stored in Excel. Office 365 security is pretty "good", too.

Comment: I didn't think about that completely. I think with the tools on Office 365, maybe I should just try to create this form on there by myself as a research project and then see if that's a viable option (depending on the controls available).